# Problem rendering info into component of aldabil scheduler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the next code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, Component } from "react";
import { Scheduler } from "@aldabil/react-scheduler";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import "./weekcalendar_1.css";

const WeekCalendar_1 = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [variable, setVariable] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("entro");
    fetchMoreData();
  }, []);

  function getCurrentMonday() {
    const today = new Date();
    const dayOfWeek = today.getDay();
    const daysUntilMonday = dayOfWeek === 0 ? 6 : dayOfWeek - 1;
    today.setDate(today.getDate() - daysUntilMonday);
    return today;
  }

  function getNextSunday() {
    const today = new Date();
    const dayOfWeek = today.getDay();
    const daysUntilSunday = 7 - dayOfWeek;
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + daysUntilSunday);
    return today;
  }

  function getFormattedCurDate(currentDate) {
    const year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    const month = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); // Months are 0-based
    const day = String(currentDate.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");

    const hours = String(currentDate.getHours()).padStart(2, "0");
    const minutes = String(currentDate.getMinutes()).padStart(2, "0");
    const seconds = String(currentDate.getSeconds()).padStart(2, "0");

    return `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  }

  const fetchMoreData = async () => {
    let params = {
      start_date: getFormattedCurDate(getCurrentMonday()),
      end_date: getFormattedCurDate(getNextSunday()),
      type: "REGISTERED",
    };

    let query = Object.keys(params)
      .map((k) => k + "=" + params[k])
      .join("&");

    var getScheduledClasses =
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/v1/class?` + query;
    fetch(getScheduledClasses, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + Cookies.get("token"),
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 403) {
          Cookies.remove("token");
          navigate("/");
        } else if (response.status == 200) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((classes) => {
        console.log(classes);
        var events = [];
        classes.forEach((e) =>
          events.push({
            event_id: e.id,
            title: e.language,
            start: new Date(e.start_date),
            end: new Date(e.end_date),
          })
        );

        setVariable({
          event_id: 1,
          title: "Event 1",
          start: new Date("2023/9/15 07:30"),
          end: new Date("2023/9/15 09:30"),
        });
        //Arreglo de eventos
        console.log(events);
        setItems(events);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        //Handle error
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="week-calendar_container">
      <div>
        {console.log(variable)}
        <Scheduler
          events={variable}
          //   {
          //     event_id: 1,
          //     title: "Event 1",
          //     start: new Date("2021/5/2 09:30"),
          //     end: new Date("2021/5/2 10:30"),
          //   },
          resourceFields={{
            //No hace nada
            idField: "name",
            textField: "name",
            colorField: "color",
          }}
          month={{
            weekDays: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            weekStartOn: 1,
            startHour: 7,
            endHour: 22,
            cellRenderer: () => <></>,
          }}
          week={{
            weekDays: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            weekStartOn: 1,
            startHour: 7,
            endHour: 22,
            step: 30,
            cellRenderer: () => <></>,
          }}
          day={{
            startHour: 7,
            endHour: 22,
            step: 30,
            cellRenderer: () => <></>,
          }}
          editable={false}
          deletable={false}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default WeekCalendar_1;
```

On this line:

```
console.log(events);
 setItems(events);
```

My events render and I can show them in console, knowing that, I need to send that info into the Scheduler component, as aldabil explains, you can show the info like this:

```
<Scheduler   view="month"   events={[     {       event_id: 1,       title: "Event 1",       start: new Date("2021/5/2 09:30"),       end: new Date("2021/5/2 10:30"),     },     {       event_id: 2,       title: "Event 2",       start: new Date("2021/5/4 10:00"),       end: new Date("2021/5/4 11:00"),     },   ]} />
```

Problem is, when I try to render the info into the events={items}, doesn't show anything
What should I do?

I tried to change the events={items}, the info is showing in the `{console.log(variable)}` like this:
`5 : {event_id: 17, title: 'EN', start: Wed Sep 13 2023 13:30:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia), end: Wed Sep 13 2023 15:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)}`